# iterate over table in 'self' function such as obj:function_name

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a class object that I want the highest key integer in the table

```
obj = {1,2,3}
obj[6] = 7
--this works with vec_len(obj)
function vec_len(a)
    if not a then return 0 end
    max_key = 0
    for k, _ in pairs(a) do
        if k > max_key then max_key = k end
    end
    return max_key
end

--but now if I want this function to be only available to my object then this 
--somehow doesn't work

function obj:vec_len()
    if not self then return 0 end
    max_key = 0
    for k, _ in pairs(self) do
        if k > max_key then max_key = k end
    end
    return max_key
end
```

I want 6 as the output. I don't know what went wrong. Could anyone help?

Comment: What isn't working about it? I mean, besides the fact that at some point, you're going to compare an integer to the string "vec_len"?

Comment: If you want `vec_len` to operate over something other than `obj`, then why did you change `a` to `self` everywhere?

Comment: sorry it was a typo, i made my edit

Comment: @Nicol Bolas Lua compiler complains about accessing nil type, which I am pretty sure is related to the function ref wasn't available when lua looked into the obj table

Comment: Replace `pairs` with `ipairs` (you key `k` might be `"vec_len"` now, this is a string, it could not be compared with a number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a meta table with the __index metamethod, pointing to a table that has your function that will call without iterating over the function (which your code does.)

```
obj = {1,2,3}
obj[6] = 7

setmetatable(obj, {
  __index = { -- set index metamethod with another table
    vec_len = function(self) -- you can call obj:vec_len() and self will be the table without the functions
      local max_key = 0

      for k, _ in pairs(self) do
        if k > max_key then
          max_key = k
        end
      end

      return max_key
    end
  }
})

---------------------
--> print(obj:vec_len())
--> 6
```

Comment: Although this solves the issue, it is perhaps not best practice.